# TableView Datasource must return a cell, check code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cell, tableview

The debugger threw me this error

`UITableView dataSource` must `return` a `cell` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

this is my code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell   = nil;
    NSString        *text   = nil;
    NSInteger       section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger       row     = indexPath.row;

    switch (section) 
    {
        case PURCHASE_SECTION:
        {   
            static NSString *cellID = @"GenericCell";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                               reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }

            switch (row) 
            {
                case CATEGORY_ROW:
                    text                        = [self.purchase.category valueForKey:@"name"];
                    cell.textLabel.text         = text;
                    cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    break;
                case TYPE_ROW:
                    text                        = [self.purchase.type valueForKey:@"name"];
                    cell.textLabel.text         = text;
                    cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    break;
                case VENDOR_ROW:
                    text                        = [self.purchase.vendor valueForKey:@"name"];
                    cell.textLabel.text         = text;
                    cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    break;
                case NOTES_ROW:
                    text                        = @"Notes";
                    cell.textLabel.text         = text;
                    cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        case ITEMS_SECTION:
        {
            NSUInteger  itemsCount = [purchase.items count];

            if (row < itemsCount) 
            {
                static NSString *itemsCellID = @"ItemsCell";

                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:itemsCellID];

                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                                   reuseIdentifier:itemsCellID] autorelease];
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }

                PurchaseItem *item          = [items objectAtIndex:row];
                cell.textLabel.text         = item.name;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text   = [item.amount formattedDataDisplay];
            } 
            else 
            {
                static NSString *AddItemCellID = @"AddItemCell";

                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AddItemCellID];

                if (cell == nil) 
                {
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                                   reuseIdentifier:AddItemCellID] autorelease];
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                }
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Item";
            }
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION_SECTION:
        {
            text = @"Purchase Location";
            cell.accessoryType          = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    return cell;
}
```

I just can't seem to spot the error, and I could use a set of fresh eyes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, now i just feel silly, it seems that i left out an important snippet of code involving the dequeueing of cell in the LOCATION_SECTION case. I added it and the error went away, and i would like to thank "rpetrich" for pointing out something i left in the code from a previous time "cell.textlabel.text = text;", and this too needed to be removed, so THANK YOU.

Answer (score 4):

`cell` is never set inside `case LOCATION_SECTION:`.

Also, sometimes you set `cell.textLabel.text` to a value in a `case` block, only to reset it to `nil` later via `cell.textLabel.text = text`. Surely this isn't intended?

Comment: shouldn't the 'cell' and 'text' variable be set outside the switch statement? and then used for each case as needed

Comment: If you want to use a `text` variable, change `cell.textLabel.text         = item.name;` to `text = item.name;` and `cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Item";` to `text = @"Add Item";`. Otherwise remove the `text` variable entirely and just assign to `cell.textLabel.text`.